# How to get CMake find_file to accept UNIX-style paths on MSYS2?

Tags: path, cmake, file-not-found, msys2

I'm using CMake 3.4.1, on Windows 10, with MSYS2 (everything up-to-date as of Dec. 25 2015).

When I use CMake's `find_file` command, it won't work unless the path is in Windows-style. This is a problem for me, because I'm trying to use `findwxWidgets.cmake`, which fails because of this.

For example:

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
find_file(version_h version.h PATHS /mingw64/include/wx-3.0/wx)
message(STATUS "version_h: ${version_h}")
```

**Running `cmake` spits out:**

```
-- version_h: version_h-NOTFOUND
```

**But it's clearly in there:**

```
>>> file /mingw64/include/wx-3.0/wx/version.h
/mingw64/include/wx-3.0/wx/version.h: C source, ASCII text
```

I'm wondering if this is a bug, or if there's some obscure flag I have to set to get this to work. How do I get CMake's `find_file` to find files with UNIX-style paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW-w64 cmake can't understand MSYS2 paths. You might propose a path transformation test program to the CMake developers, but that's fairly gross and I'd hope the would reject that. Instead these things must be solved case-by-case. wx-config, being a shell script, is providing an MSYS2 path.

This is a bug in the currently release MSYS2 wxWidgets packages that will be fixed in the next release. To work around it, find the line in /mingw64/bin/wx-config or /mingw32/bin/wx-config:

```
prefix=${input_option_prefix-${this_prefix:-/mingw64}}
```

(or /mingw32 of course) and add after it:

```
if [ "x${MSYSTEM}" = "xMINGW32" ] || [ "x${MSYSTEM}" = "xMINGW64" ]; then
    prefix=$(cygpath -m ${prefix})
fi
```

Be careful to remove it at upgrade time though.